# CA2012 warning when using ValueTask with discard

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, valuetask

I am making a simple TCP server and stumbled on this [article](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html) by Marc Gravell mentioning the following:

> Use ValueTask[], unless you absolutely can't because the existing API is Task[], and even then: at least consider an API break

So I changed my `HandleClient()` method to return `ValueTask` rather than `Task`:

```
public async Task Start()
{
    TcpListener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine($"Server started. Listening on {ServerIP}:{ServerPort}");

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = await TcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            _ = HandleClient(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error accepting client: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

private async ValueTask HandleClient(TcpClient client) 
{
    ...
    int bytes = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, cts.Token);
    ...
    await stream.WriteAsync(response);
    ...
}
```

After changing the return type to ValueTask though, I am getting the following warning:
`CA2012: ValueTask instances returned from method calls should always be used, typically awaited. Not doing so often represents a functional bug, but even if it doesn't, it can result in degraded performance if the target method pools objects for use with ValueTasks.`

However, I cannot use `await` here because the while loop has to keep running to accept connections concurrently while `HandleClient()` executes on a different thread.
From this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3617), it is suggested to use `HandleClient().Preserve()`, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of changing my method to `ValueTask` since according to [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.preserve?view=net-7.0):

> You can use the Preserve() method to convert this ValueTask into the instance backed by a regular Task that is safe to await multiple times.

So, if I use `Preserve()` then I am basically using a regular `Task` from what I understand, and I might as well just change `HandleClient()` back to return `Task` instead.

I also tried assigning it to a variable and doing so does get rid of the warning, but I don't know if that solves the problem (if it even exists).

```
var t = HandleClient(client);
```

This assignment also does *not* give me the regular warning `CS0129: The variable is assigned but its value is never used`, so maybe that is actually the solution?

Comment: Per this link: [C# Async Task Method Without Await or Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187544/c-sharp-async-task-method-without-await-or-return):  "You only mark a method as async if you're planning on using an await (directly) inside of it. The fact that it returns a Task is enough to satisfy the interface; async/await are irrespective of interfaces."  So just remove the "async", remove the "var t =" ... and you should be good to go :)

Comment: I didn't include this in my post, but my HandleClient() method uses await inside by calling await stream.ReadAsync(buffer)

Comment: OK: if you actually *NEED* "await" in the *SAME* method, then another approach might be to [suppress the CA2012 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings) for that particular module.

Comment: This is a question that @MarcGravell should answer, since he is the culprit of the [original article](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html). :-)

Comment: PS: It sounds like plain old "Task" is perfectly OK in this case :)

Comment: Yeah, I will probably just switch back to Task now. I just decided to use it since @MarcGravell recommended it as the default choice basically. Also it's not like my server is handling thousands of requests per second to benefit from any performance boost using ValueTask lol.

Comment: Have you considered changing the return type to `void`?